# How to efficiently check a Vec<u8> to see if it's all zeros?

Tags: rust, vector

I have many 4KiB buffers, which have a 50% chance of containing only zero values.  The non-zero buffers will typically have a non-zero byte early in the buffer.

```
fn is_zero(buf: &Vec<u8>) -> bool {
    for byte in buf.into_iter() {
        if *byte != 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is this a performant way of checking in Rust, with `--release`?  (I am processing many GBs of data.)

(In the C version, I cast the buffer to `unsigned long long` before checking.  That probably wasn't the best I could do, given SSE etc.)

Comment: Not directly related to performance, but one thing you should do is change the argument to `&[u8]` to avoid double indirection (if not optimized out in the first place).  See [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/9716597).  And remove the redundant `.into_iter` as well.

Comment: You can write it as `buf.into_iter().all(|&b| b == 0)` which is (IMHO) clear enough that it doesn't require a separate function in the first place. In release mode performance should be equivalent to that of a manual loop.

Comment: It's a shame that there is no negative-match variant of `memchr`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You an use [`align_to`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.align_to) to convert the slice of `u8` into a slice of `u128`, making the comparison more efficient:

```rust
fn is_zero(buf: &[u8]) -> bool {
    let (prefix, aligned, suffix) = unsafe { buf.align_to::<u128>() };

    prefix.iter().all(|&x| x == 0)
        && suffix.iter().all(|&x| x == 0)
        && aligned.iter().all(|&x| x == 0)
}
```

Running a simple benchmark on my machine shows 16x performance gains!

```rust
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

fn v() -> Vec<u8> {
    std::iter::repeat(0).take(1000000).collect()
}

fn is_zero(buf: &[u8]) -> bool {
    buf.into_iter().all(|&b| b == 0)
}

fn is_zero_aligned(buf: &[u8]) -> bool {
    let (prefix, aligned, suffix) = unsafe { buf.align_to::<u128>() };

    prefix.iter().all(|&x| x == 0)
        && suffix.iter().all(|&x| x == 0)
        && aligned.iter().all(|&x| x == 0)
}

#[bench]
fn bench_is_zero(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let v = test::black_box(v());
    b.iter(|| is_zero(&v[..]))
}

#[bench]
fn bench_is_zero_aligned(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let v = test::black_box(v());
    b.iter(|| is_zero_aligned(&v[..]))
}
```

```sh
running 2 tests
test tests::bench_is_zero         ... bench:     455,975 ns/iter (+/- 414)
test tests::bench_is_zero_aligned ... bench:      28,615 ns/iter (+/- 116)
```

Depending on your machine, different integer types (`u64`) may yield better performance.

*Thanks to @Globi on the Rust discord server for the idea*

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware of `align_to`.

Answer (score 4):

Found 4x speedup on my laptop with `byteorder`, by reading `u64` at a time, in native endian.

### lib.rs

```rust
extern crate byteorder;

use byteorder::{NativeEndian, ReadBytesExt};
use std::io::Cursor;

pub fn one(buf: &[u8]) -> bool {
    buf.into_iter().all(|&byte| byte == 0)
}

pub fn two(buf: &[u8]) -> bool {
    let mut cur = Cursor::new(buf);
    while let Ok(val) = cur.read_u64::<NativeEndian>() {
        if val != 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    while let Ok(val) = cur.read_u8() {
        if val != 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}
```

### benches/benches.rs

```rust
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;
extern crate zero_slice_8;

use zero_slice_8::{one, two};

fn v() -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut result = vec![];
    for _ in 0..100000 {
        result.push(0);
    }
    result
}

#[bench]
fn bench_one(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let v = v();
    b.iter(|| one(&v[..]))
}

#[bench]
fn bench_two(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let v = v();
    b.iter(|| two(&v[..]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function is pure save *Rust*:

```
fn is_zero ( slice : &[u8] ) -> bool {
    for i in (0..slice.len()).step_by(16) {
        if slice.len() - i >= 16 {
            let arr : [u8; 16] = slice[i..i+16].try_into().expect("this should always succeed");
            if u128::from_be_bytes(arr) != 0 {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            for i in i..slice.len() {
                if slice[i] != 0 {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Specifically, it uses the `u128::from_be_bytes` function to convert a `[u8; 16]` array to a `u128` as a non-op, and uses the `TryInto` trait to turn a `[u8]` of appropriate length into a `[u8; 16]` — the rest is fairly trivial. It is possible to manually unroll the inner loop to convert it, but I doubt this will be a significant performance bottleneck that the `u8`s that form the tail of the list that aren't cleanly 16 bytes would work.

Depending on the processor, using `u64` or even `u32` might be faster, one would have to profile that for oneself.

Comment: Can the `try_into` fail if the slice is not 16-byte aligned?

Comment: @PeterHall no it won't fail because of alignment; it can only fail because of length. I checked the implementation. You may be thinking of SSE, where some instructions may fail when given an unaligned address.

Comment: Hm so what happens on architectures that can't handle misaligned integers?

Comment: @PeterHall The small array is stored on the stack before it becomes an integer. So on architectures that forbid misaligned integer loads, the array load may become a series of byte loads. However, popular architectures allow misaligned word loads, even if this lack of alignment comes with an additional performance penalty, typically only when loads cross the cache-line or even page boundary.

So, good, you found a (small) flaw in the response.

Comment: @Peter_Hall, it wouldn't fail, but that's a very good point for optimization as a misaligned one would obviously be slower to convert. A proper implementation would also do the head of the list seperately until reaching an aligned pointer and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [rayon](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon), a data parallelism library that seems like a good fit for your use case. It is very simple to use: Just change `buf.iter()` into `buf.par_iter()`, and Rayon does the rest:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn is_zero_par(buf: &[u8]) -> bool {
    buf.par_iter().all(|&b| b == 0)
}
```

For a vector of 20 million elements, rayon shows a 7x increase in performance:

```rust
#![feature(test)]
use rayon::prelude::*;
extern crate test;

fn v() -> Vec<u8> {
    std::iter::repeat(0).take(20000000).collect()
}

fn is_zero(buf: &[u8]) -> bool {
    buf.into_iter().all(|&b| b == 0)
}

fn is_zero_par(buf: &[u8]) -> bool {
    buf.par_iter().all(|&b| b == 0)
}

#[bench]
fn bench_is_zero(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let v = test::black_box(v());
    b.iter(|| is_zero(&v[..]))
}

#[bench]
fn bench_is_zero_par(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let v = test::black_box(v());
    b.iter(|| is_zero_par(&v[..]))
}
```

```sh
running 2 tests
test tests::bench_is_zero     ... bench:   7,217,686 ns/iter (+/- 478,845)
test tests::bench_is_zero_par ... bench:   1,080,959 ns/iter (+/- 111,692)
```

Note that the performance impact of multi-threading depends on the workload (number of elements), and smaller workloads may get impacted negatively.

Comment: May not get as much benefit for OP's much smaller buffers though.

Comment: @PeterHall It would be just as easy to iterate over buffers in parallel, and for each buffer simply iterate over bytes sequentially. However, OP did not provide any code to shed some light on his collection of buffers.